# Unable to make Angular work with CSS 3D

Tags: html, css, angularjs, 3d, flip

I have a simple `div` which flips when the text is clicked. I am using Angular but once the `div` flips it does not return to its normal state when clicked again.
**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s3j51bmg/)**

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app>
    <div>
        <div id="content_wrapper">
            <div id="flip_wrapper" ng-init="show_case='employee'" class="transition_long {{show_case == employer}}">
                <div id="employee_wrapper" class="flip_case">
                    <div ng-click="show_case = employer" class="clickme">click to flip</div>
                </div>
                <div id="employer_wrapper" class="flip_case">
                    <div ng-click="show_case = employee" class="clickme">back to where we were</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#content_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    perspective: 2000;
}

#flip_wrapper {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}


#flip_wrapper.false {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

#flip_wrapper.true {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip_case {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip_case#employee_wrapper {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip_case#employer_wrapper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fiddle where I have it working though moving the logic into a controller http://jsfiddle.net/7zwuw311/1/

```
<body ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
       <div id="content_wrapper">
           <div id="flip_wrapper" class="transition_long {{show_case}}">
               <div id="employee_wrapper" class="flip_case">
                   <div ng-click="toggleShowCase()" class="clickme">click to flip</div>
               </div>
               <div id="employer_wrapper" class="flip_case">
                   <div ng-click="toggleShowCase()" class="clickme">back to where we were</div>

               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>


angular.module('app', [])

angular.module('app')
  .controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl( $scope) {
    $scope.show_case = false;

      $scope.toggleShowCase = function(){
         $scope.show_case = !$scope.show_case;
      }

 });
```